# erro no envioSMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Tags: php

Olá pessoal estou desenvolvendo um projeto e terá uma pagina de contato, porém esta dando o seguinte erro:

erro no envioSMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

PS: Estou usando o plugin phpmailer

php mailer:

```
<?php

 /**
* descricao EmailEnviar
*
* @author adrianosites.com.br
*/
class EmailEnviar extends PHPMailer {


/**
 * inicia os dados de conexao com o host
 * 
 */
function __construct() {

    $this->isSMTP();
    $this->isHTML(true);
    $this->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $this->Port = 587;
    $this->SMTPDebug = 0;
    $this->SMTPSecure = "tls";  
    $this->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $this->SMTPAuth   = true;  
    $this->Username   = "janainatutor@hotmail.com"; 
    $this->Password   = "xxxxxxxxxx";        // SMTP account password
    //$this->SetFrom('janainatutor@hotmail.com', 'Adriano sites php 
    imoveis');
    $this->From  = 'janainatutor@hotmail.com';
    $this->FromName = 'Acordo Imóvel';


}

/**
 * 
 * @param type $destinatario
 * @param type $assunto
 * @param type $msg
 * 
 *  envia o email
 */
public function Enviar($destinatario,$assunto,$msg) {



    $this->Subject = $assunto;
    $this->addAddress($destinatario);
    $this->Body = $msg;


    if(parent::send()):

        parent::clearAllRecipients();
        else:

        echo 'erro no envio' . $this->ErrorInfo ;
    endif;


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Você está utilizando o servidor do Gmail e utilizando uma conta do Hotmail, utilize uma conta do Gmail, como no exemplo:

```
function __construct() {

    $this->isSMTP();
    $this->isHTML(true);
    $this->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $this->Port = 587;
    $this->SMTPDebug = 0;
    $this->SMTPSecure = "tls";  
    $this->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $this->SMTPAuth   = true;  
    $this->Username   = "velasco@gmail.com"; 
    $this->Password   = "xxxxxxxxxx";        // SMTP account password
    //$this->SetFrom('janainatutor@hotmail.com', 'Adriano sites php 
    imoveis');
    $this->From  = 'velasco@gmail.com';
    $this->FromName = 'Acordo Imóvel';


}
```

Answer (score -1):

Utilize a porta 465 e segurança ssl:

```
$this->Port = 465;<br/>
$this->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
```